# Where is /var/log/daemon.log on 22.04 server on Pi4

Tags: logs

Wanting to learn more about logs.
Reading thru
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/viewing-and-monitoring-log-files#2-log-files-locations
Noticing that
/var/log/daemon.log
&
/var/log/debug
are not visible
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possibly helpful: `less /var/log/README` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 - thank you - but sadly not: cat: /var/log/README: No such file or directory

Comment: Read `man journalctl`. `journalctl` is the modern way, much better than trying to guess which log file(s) has the messages you care about. Click on my name, read my Profile

Comment: In my profile, after the Brags and Rants, I have hints to make using `journalctl` easier.